# How can I really master in game programming?

Tags: software-engineering

Game Programming is fun and interesting.

To develop games I have to learn several languages, game engines and should have sound knowledge in Math.

But what I'm really looking is how to be a **master** in **Game Programming**.

---

I have read a nice question and answer

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165380/how-can-i-really-master-a-programming-language

But here, in my question I want to know **specially regarding Game Programming from the Game Programmers.**

Your suggestions would help me to be a master in game programming.

Comment: I don't think this is really on topic for this site.  We tend to prefer specific, answerable problems.  I don't think anybody is going to be able to give you any answer other than, essentially, "practice".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make games.

... that's all I've got.  You want to master *anything*, you practice it until you have.  That's all the other great game makers have done: make lots of games.  The experienced people who frequent this site?  Check their credentials, you'll see they've made a lot of games.

That's it.  Practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Make lots of games. If you really want to focus on mastering, you need depth and breadth. This means:

- Make different types of games. Pong has totally different challenges from a 2D RPG.
- Challenge yourself. Try to solve "hard" problems or technical growth (eg. different architectures, like an entity/component system).

Also, read widely in your field. Read GameDev.SE, read game development blogs, and implement things that look cool, fun, or interesting.

Comment: +1 for this being basically what I have been doing for the past 4 months.

Comment: @Garan me too, except for a couple of years. This really worked well for me personally.

Comment: +1 for "read game development blogs, and implement things that look cool, fun, or interesting".